# c++ libconfig ambiguous overload

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous, libconfig

I'm about to compile a pretty easy 'Hello, world' using libconfig. But when I compile such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libconfig.h++>

libconfig::Config cfg;

std::string target = "World";

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        cfg.readFile("greetings.cfg");
    }
    catch (const libconfig::FileIOException &fioex)
    {
        std::cerr << "I/O error while reading file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (const libconfig::ParseException &pex)
    {
        std::cerr << pex.getFile() << " " << pex.getLine()
              << ": " << pex.getError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    try
    {
        target = cfg.lookup("target");
    }
    catch (const libconfig::SettingNotFoundException &nfex)
    {
        std::cerr << "No target set in configuration file. Using default." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Hello, " << target << "!" << std::endl;   

    return 0;
}
```

I have this error:

```
example1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
example1.cpp:28: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' in 'target = cfg.libconfig::Config::lookup(((const char*)"target"))

/usr/include/c++/4.2/bits/basic_string.h:490: note: candidates are: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2/bits/basic_string.h:498: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2/bits/basic_string.h:509: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Chapter 4 of the documentation](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig.pdf), on page 19, `lookup` returns a `Setting&`, not a string.

Now, according to page 20, `Setting` has a bunch of implicit conversions to various types, including `std::string`. Here, the conversion to `std::string` is ambiguous in the presence of the conversion to `const char*`, since `std::string` has constructors accepting both with equal rank.

**This problem is actually explicitly described on page 21**, wherein resolving the ambiguity with an explicit conversion (or "cast") is suggested, or the use of the member `c_str()` rather than of the conversion operators:

```
target = cfg.lookup("target").c_str();
```

Comment: It also won't compile too with `target = static_cast<std::string>(cfg.lookup("target"));`
`example1.cpp:34: error: call of overloaded 'basic_string(libconfig::Setting&)' is ambiguous
`